# How to check for read and write permission in C++ using std::filesystem

Tags: c++, linux, windows, unix, filesystems

I have a unix codebase that is using access(path, W_OK) and access(path, R_OK), available in unistd.h, in order to see if the file is writeable/readable.
Examples at the end of the page [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=ssw_ibm_i_73/apis/access.html).

I have seen that Windows offer the same function, under the name of [_access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/access-waccess?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-170), but I wanted an implementation leveraging only std::filesystem available in C++17.

I thought about using [std::filesystem::perms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/perms) and perform a manual check for both read and write, but how can I pefectly mimick the checks made by access?

Comment: Don't forget that permissions can be changed by another process after you checked for them. It's possible that you check permissions observing you can read the file, and then fail to open said file for reading since the permissions have been changed. It's fine to check permissions (e.g. to show them to the user in a file manager GUI), but there's no way to truly know if you can open a file than trying to open it.

Answer (score 2):

See the reference [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/permissions)
If you want to check you can use this:

```
std::filesystem::status("filename").permissions()
```

That will give you list of permissions. And you can use some approach like this:

```
#include <filesystem>
#define F_OK 0
#define R_OK 1
#define W_OK 2
#define X_OK 3
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int access(const fs::path& path, int amode){
    auto a=fs::status(path).permissions();
    switch(amode){
    case F_OK:
        return fs::perms::unknown!=a? 0 : -1;
    case R_OK:
        return (fs::perms::owner_read & a) == fs::perms::owner_read ? 0 : -1;
    case W_OK:
        return (fs::perms::owner_read & a) == fs::perms::owner_read  && (fs::perms::owner_write & a) == fs::perms::owner_write ? 0 : -1;
    case X_OK:
        return (fs::perms::owner_read & a) == fs::perms::owner_read  && (fs::perms::owner_exec & a) == fs::perms::owner_exec ? 0 : -1;
    default:
        return -1;
    }
}
```

This might not work as you expected because I don't even controlled file owner is me or Am I in same group with group owner. You need to check each case, for example," read can be operate, whether file have `owner_read` and you are the file owner or file have `group_read` and you are same group with file owner or file have `others_read`"
It makes something more complicated.

You need to check something like that and it is so complex I guess.

Or you can easily use [fstat](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat) for Unix and [GetFileAttributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesa?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for Windows and in your code just check whether your system is Unix or Windows using directives.

Comment: Since you are doing modern C++, can you avoid raw pointers please? Why not `std::filesystem::path` as first argument for  code clarity? Also, you can be more readable, using a using declaration (`using std::filesystem::perms;`) inside the function.